# Построчно смещается текст при записи в текстовый файл в Python

Tags: python

Я хочу, чтобы значения словаря записывались построчно в текстовом файле, но при прибавлении значений почему-то прибавляется к следующей строке, то есть

```
0
0
0
0
0
5
0
```

переходит в

```
0
0
0
0
0
5
5
```

вместо

```
0
0
0
0
0
10
0
```

код:

```
from sys import exit

# словарь ресурсов
resources = {
    "Железо": 0,
    "Золото": 0,
    "Дерево": 0,
    "Ингридиенты": 0, 
    "Кожа": 0,
    "Еда": 0,
    "Электричество": 0
}

# словарь нужд
needs = {
    "Жажда": 0, 
    "Голод": 0,
}

# описание функции записи ресурсов 
def recordData(resDict: dict, filename: str):

    # values - список значений словаря-аргумента
    values = list(resDict.values())
    
    # открытие файла сохранений
    textFile = open(filename, 'w')

    # цикл, записывающий по строке для каждого значения
    for i in range(len(values)):
        if i < len(values):
            textFile.write(str(values[i]) + "\n")
        else:
            textFile.write(str(values[i]))  
        i += 1
    
    # закрытие файла
    textFile.close()

# функция выставления ресурсов из файла в словарь
def setData(resDict: dict, filename: str):
    
    # список ключей словаря аргумента
    keys = list(resDict.keys())

    try:
    # открытие текстового файла
        textFile = open(filename, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('\n Ошибка. Нет файла сохранения')
        print('\n Создаём файлы сохранения...')

        textFile = open(filename, 'w')

        for i in range(len(keys)):
            textFile.write(str(0) + '\n')
        print('\n Файлы сохранения созданы.')

        textFile.close()

        textFile = open(filename, 'r')
    # выходной словарь
    out_dict = {}


    # lines - список строк из текствого файла
    lines = textFile.readlines()

    if len(lines) < len(keys):
        textFile.close()

        textFile = open(filename, 'a')

        for i in range(len(keys) - len(lines)):
            textFile.write(str(0)+'\n')
        textFile.close()
        textFile = open(filename, 'r')    

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        # преобразование строк в список Интежеров
        lines[i] = int(str(lines[i])[:-1])
        i += 1
    

    for i in range(len(keys)):
        # ключ i равен строчке i
        out_dict[keys[i]] = lines[i]

    textFile.close()
    
    # возврат итогового словаря
    return out_dict

resources = setData(resources, 'resources.txt')
needs = setData(needs, 'needs.txt')

needs['Жажда'] += 2

resources['Еда'] += 5

recordData(resources, 'resources.txt')
recordData(needs, 'needs.txt')
```

можете объяснить?

Comment: Используйте стандартный модуль `json`, пишите словари в `JSON` файл и не мучайтесь с этой всей ерундой. Очень легко читать-писать такие данные, пара строк буквально.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо crazyElf за комментарий, чтобы упаковать любые выражения в строку, используйте json.dumps и json.loads

Comment: Да можно даже прямо в файл, а не в строку, через dump и load без буквы s в конце.

Comment: окей, посмотрю, но это прям для новичков по типу меня(с буквой s)